# Header only retrieval in php via curl

Tags: php, curl, header

Actually I have two questions.

(1) Is there any reduction in *processing power* or *bandwidth* used on remote server if I retrieve only headers as opposed to full page retrieval using php and curl?

(2) Since I think, and I might be wrong, that answer to first questions is *YES*, I am trying to get last modified date or If-Modified-Since header of remote file only in order to compare it with time-date of locally stored data, so I can, in case it has been changed, store it locally. However, my script seems unable to fetch that piece of info, I get `NULL`, when I run this:

```
class last_change {

 public last_change;

 function set_last_change() {
  $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://url/file.xml");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
  // $header = curl_exec($curl);
  $this -> last_change = curl_getinfo($header);
  curl_close($curl);
 }

 function get_last_change() {
  return $this -> last_change['datetime']; // I have tested with Last-Modified & If-Modified-Since to no avail
 }

}
```

In case `$header = curl_exec($curl)` is uncomented, header data is displayed, even if I haven't requested it and is as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 04 Sep 2009 12:15:51 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.8 (Linux/SUSE)
Last-Modified: Thu, 03 Sep 2009 12:46:54 GMT
ETag: "198054-118c-472abc735ab80"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 4492
Content-Type: text/xml
```

Based on that, 'Last-Modified' is returned.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You are passing $header to `curl_getinfo()`. It should be `$curl` (the curl handle). You can get just the `filetime` by passing `CURLINFO_FILETIME` as the second parameter to `curl_getinfo()`. (Often the `filetime` is unavailable, in which case it will be reported as -1).

Your class seems to be wasteful, though, throwing away a lot of information that could be useful. Here's another way it might be done:

```
class URIInfo 
{
    public $info;
    public $header;
    private $url;

    public function __construct($url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->setData();
    }

    public function setData() 
    {
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        $this->header = curl_exec($curl);
        $this->info = curl_getinfo($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
    }

    public function getFiletime() 
    {
        return $this->info['filetime'];
    }

    // Other functions can be added to retrieve other information.
}

$uri_info = new URIInfo('http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/');
$filetime = $uri_info->getFiletime();
if ($filetime != -1) {
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $filetime);
} else {
    echo 'filetime not available';
}
```

Yes, the load will be lighter on the server, since it's only returning only the HTTP header (responding, after all, to a `HEAD` request). How much lighter will vary greatly.

Comment: It is to be noted that the above code will not return any headers, just the info vars. To retrieve headers too you need to add `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);` . The headers come in plaint text form though and need to be parsed afterwards.

Answer (score 43):

Why use CURL for this? There is a PHP-function for that:

```
$headers=get_headers("http://www.amazingjokes.com/img/2014/530c9613d29bd_CountvonCount.jpg");
print_r($headers);
```

returns the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [1] => Date: Tue, 11 Mar 2014 22:44:38 GMT
    [2] => Server: Apache
    [3] => Last-Modified: Tue, 25 Feb 2014 14:08:40 GMT
    [4] => ETag: "54e35e8-8873-4f33ba00673f4"
    [5] => Accept-Ranges: bytes
    [6] => Content-Length: 34931
    [7] => Connection: close
    [8] => Content-Type: image/jpeg
)
```

Should be easy to get the content-type after this.

You could also add the format=1 to get_headers:

```
$headers=get_headers("http://www.amazingjokes.com/img/2014/530c9613d29bd_CountvonCount.jpg",1);
    print_r($headers);
```

This will return the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [Date] => Tue, 11 Mar 2014 22:44:38 GMT
    [Server] => Apache
    [Last-Modified] => Tue, 25 Feb 2014 14:08:40 GMT
    [ETag] => "54e35e8-8873-4f33ba00673f4"
    [Accept-Ranges] => bytes
    [Content-Length] => 34931
    [Connection] => close
    [Content-Type] => image/jpeg
)
```

[More reading here (PHP.NET)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)

Comment: Just note that according to php docs this will do a GET request instead of a HEAD request, which seems inefficient.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php#example-4203

Comment: @Tim, indeed, didn't know that. Shall I edit this post to reflect the more efficient way suggested on PHP.NET? I know I will adapt my programming to this!

Comment: CURL is necessary if someone wants to get header while using cookies.

Comment: This method only works if "allow_url_fopen" is set to true (1) in php.ini

Answer (score 15):

(1) Yes. A HEAD request (as you're issuing in this case) is far lighter on the server because it only returns the HTTP headers, as opposed to the headers and content like a standard GET request.

(2) You need to set the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option to `true` before you call `curl_exec()` to have the content returned, as opposed to printed:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

That should also make your class work correctly.

Answer (score 6):

You can set the default stream context:

```
stream_context_set_default(
    array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'HEAD'
        )
    )
);
```

Then use:

```
$headers = get_headers($url,1);
```

get_headers seems to be more efficient than cURL once get_headers skip steps like trigger authentication routines such as log in prompts or cookies.

Comment: Can also be done without setting the default: `get_headers($url, 1, stream_context_create(array('http' => array('method' => 'HEAD')))`. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php

Answer (score 6):

Here is my implementation using CURLOPT_HEADER, then parsing the output string into a map:

```
function http_headers($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

    $headers = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    $data = [];
    $headers = explode(PHP_EOL, $headers);
    foreach ($headers as $row) {
        $parts = explode(':', $row);
        if (count($parts) === 2) {
            $data[trim($parts[0])] = trim($parts[1]);
        }
    }

    return $data;
};
```

Sample usage:

```
$headers = http_headers('https://i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/g-dKXOlsf98/hqdefault.webp');
print_r($headers);

Array
(
    ['Content-Type'] => 'image/webp'
    ['ETag'] => '1453807629'
    ['X-Content-Type-Options'] => 'nosniff'
    ['Server'] => 'sffe'
    ['Content-Length'] => 32958
    ['X-XSS-Protection'] => '1; mode=block'
    ['Age'] => 11
    ['Cache-Control'] => 'public, max-age=7200'
)
```

Comment: I tried this, but it misses headers with `:` in the values, like `Last-Modified: Mon, 01 Oct 2018 21:57:45 GMT`

Comment: headers are separated with \r\n
Using PHP_EOL is the wrong way to do it there :  `$headers = explode(PHP_EOL, $headers);`

you should do `$headers = explode("\r\n", $headers);`

Answer (score 4):

You need to add

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

to return the header instead of printing it.

Whether returning only the headers is lighter on the server depends on the script that's running, but usually it will be.

I think you also want "filetime" instead of "datetime".