# Test if webpage is responding via php

Tags: php, url, html, ping

I'm trying to build a basic "status" page using php that will tell my users if various services (webpages we use) are at least serving up pages (which isn't 100% guarantee of working but its pretty good indicator)

what i would like to do is something like

www.domainname.com/mediawiki/index.php and make sure that returns the page or not

I'm pretty new to php so im not even sure what function im looking for.

Thanks

Comment: Do not forget whatever the solutions you take, you can "play" with timeouts. For example file_get_contents you can set the function timeout directly in the third parameter. See: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 5):

There are ways to use built-in PHP functions to do this (e.g. file_get_contents), but they aren't very good. I suggest you take a look at the excellent cURL library. This might point you in the right direction: [Header only retrieval in php via curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378915/header-only-retreival-in-php-via-curl)

Since you just want to see if a page is "up" you don't need to request the whole page, you can just use a HEAD request to get the headers for the page.

Comment: file_get_contents is disabled on many shared hosting systems and it returns more data than you need to determine if the page is available.

Comment: True but you'd be surprised how many scripts are (misguidedly) written to die on HEAD. Plus, you can set file_get_contents to perform a HEAD request. Either way, I'd suggest searching the returned source for a certain string for better determination.

Comment: @Alan and `cURL` is always enabled? I dont think so.

Comment: @Cybrix cURL is not always enabled either, but most places I have seen file_get_contents disabled, cURL is.  If you have it available, cURL is usually a better choice due to its flexibility, but you have to just use what you have available on your system.

Comment: @webbiedave That's a good point, you would have to see what you the script you are using returns.  And if it is not a very large page, it won't make much of a difference anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

It will return the web page source as a string. This way you could even search the string for a specific value, if so desired, for finer results. **This can be very useful in case content is still returned but is some sort of error message.**

```
$somePage = file_get_contents('http://www.domainname.com/mediawiki/index.php');
// $somePage now contains the HTML source or false if failed
```

Ensure `allow_url_fopen = On` in your php.ini

If you need to check the response headers, you can use [$http_response_header](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $_URL = "http://www.domainname.com/mediawiki/index.php";

    if (! @file_get_contents($_URL))
    {
        echo "Service not responding.";
    }
?>
```

Note that your `php.ini` must activate `allow_url_fopen`

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to see of the socket is responding.
(I can't remember where I got this from originally but it lets me know if port 80 is responding).  You could always direct this to a different port.

```
function server($addr){
    if(strstr($addr,'/')){$addr = substr($addr, 0, strpos($addr, '/'));}
    return $addr;
};    

$link    = 'secure.sdinsite.net:';
$s_link  = str_replace('::', ':', $link);
$address = explode (':',"$s_link");
$churl   = @fsockopen(server($addrress[0]), 80, $errno, $errstr, 20);

if (!$churl) {
    $status = 'dead';
} else {
    $status = 'live';
};

echo $status;
```