# How to find out when a web page was last changed?

Tags: php, header, http-headers

Is there a way to find out when a web page was last changed using PHP? (The web page is hosted on a different website).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use that lame method :

`$checksum = md5(file_get_contents("http://www.site.com"));`

You can store that value and compare it later.

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

Last-Modified header in http.
But there is no guarantee it will function correctly. Last modified header can be set incorrectly, or not set at all.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just use curl and pull the header out.

I would check out this similar question / answer:

[Header only retrieval in php via curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378915/header-only-retreival-in-php-via-curl/1379319#1379319)

Answer (score 1):

Using cUrl , you can check the headers but if they are not set corectly then you're lost . The only thing i can think of is testing if the content has chaged , you can get the contet of the homepage with cUrl or file_get_contents() ( if it's allowed on you're host ) , hash it and save it in a database , then when you whant to check again you can make a cUrl request , hash the result and check with the one you got in you're database .

Comment: @Cybrix: maybe if you didn't posted it nobody would have noticed mine since i didn't entered any code ( usualy works that way around here ) , it should be all good if the right answer was aproved ( doesn't matter if it's mine or you'res , we both try to help ) .