# Simple html dom only parsing the titles and links that contain pdf links

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I tried to parse some html page :

```
<div class="gs_r"><h3 class="gs_rt"><span class="gs_ctc">[BOOK]</span> <a href="http://exampleA.com" onmousedown="return scife_clk(this.href,'','res','1')">titleA</a></h3><div class="gs_ggs gs_fl"><a href="http://exampleApdf.pdf" onmousedown="return scife_clk(this.href,'gga','gga','1')">
<div class="gs_r"><h3 class="gs_rt"><span class="gs_ctc">[BOOK]</span> <a href="http://exampleB.com" onmousedown="return scife_clk(this.href,'','res','1')">titleB</a></h3><div class="gs_ggs gs_fl"><a href="http://exampleB.doc" onmousedown="return scife_clk(this.href,'gga','gga','1')">
```

From that html page, we can get informations: links of pages (http://exampleA.com,http://exampleB.com), titles (titleA, titleB), links of documents (http://exampleApdf.pdf,http://exampleB.doc)
But, I just want to get the informations of documents that have pdf link. so from that example, I just want to get : http://exampleA.com, titleA, http://exampleApdf.pdf. I've trying, but it gives me blank result. How can I them? thank you ! :)
here's the code :

```
<?php

include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$url = 'http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=data+mining&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=';
$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach($html->find('div[class=gs_ggs gs_fl]')as $pdfLink){
    if (preg_match('/\.pdf$/i', $pdfLink)) {
       $html2->find('span[class=gs_ctc]');
       echo $html2.$pdfLink;
    }
 }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot determine from the URL what kind of resource will be returned.

Not everyone serves up PDF files with `.pdf` extensions.  Not all web services reveal the file names of files on disk.  Only the `Content-Type` HTTP response header should be used for determining the type of the resource.

You can get this efficiently by [doing a HEAD request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1378915/362536) for each URL you find.

Comment: oh yes, thank you, I'll learn about it. but is it ok if I combine curl and simple_html_dom in the same time? cause I need to get the informations of links and titles too..

Comment: @igos, Yes, absolutely.  Remember to set a timeout on your cURL requests.