# Check if a remote url is an image via curl

Tags: php, curl

Via curl from url i getting some info and i need to check if it is an image.

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

UPDATE:
Content-type checking is not a good idea, because it can be faked.

Comment: @asprin just show where i need check.

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov  just show where i need check

Comment: The content type header cannot be faked. It is, by definition, authoritative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would personally use gd tools within PHP to check if its an image or not. You cannot trust that the source gives the right MIME within the header. More than once I have trusted the headers and been disappionted by the fact that the content was an image but was transferred (due to the way the url/server works) over another format.

Comment: Yap, you unly one who understood this question.

Comment: @user1564141 Indeed, also Alexander does, hes actually got a code sample for you.

Comment: Yes, but i working with curl and so i need to check its result.

Comment: @user1564141 Ah yea that has to take a URL which is annoying, you can use `imagecreatefromstring` http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php as a replacement

Comment: @verisimilitude This is not a security issue. If you have security concerns about the content type header, you equally should have security concerns about the content itself.

Comment: Ok. deleted my comment. above.

Comment: @verisimilitude and @oswald This is a security issue. Content-type is not authoritive and can be manipulated by the user. Imagine an upload form which allows the grabbing of remote URLs (which many do). The user ups a server with a path of `g.png` which actually points to `g.php` but gives a content-type of `image/png` but it actually downloads a PHP script to your server. If you rely only on the content-type you will download that script and when previewing the image, potentially run it on your server and so the user could gain access to running PHP scripts on your server.

Comment: @Oswald and @verisimilitude `imagecreatefromstring` prevents this by validating the content you receive from the URL. If it cannot form an image from the content it will return false. As such you should ditch the URL. Of course you should use more complex validation but that is the first step to validating content from other servers.

Comment: @Sammaye The security issue is somewhere else: not taking adequate precautions that the webserver never executes the file. PHP code can be embedded into perfectly valid images. In this case, `imagecreatefromstring` would not fail and does not prevent anything.

Comment: @Oswald Yes I know of the gif exploit that is why I said it was the first step.

Answer (score 2):

```
function getContentType($url)
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array( $curl, array(
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_NOBODY => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url ) );

    curl_exec( $curl ); //execute
    $contentType = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);  //get content type
    curl_close( $curl );

    return $contentType;
}
```

The above function will return you the type and then u can check for substring `image` in value returned

Comment: that's a quite bad url encoding practice

Comment: but what to do in case if an url is already encoded (i.e it contains %2B or %20) and it also includes chars like (" " and "+") which needs to be encoded. In that case using urlencode results in bad url i.e it will encode "%".. any idea what to do in that case

Comment: @Uttara I believe urlencode works a lot like htmlentities to detect special characters within the URL that could pose a problem is left unsanistised. As such if the url is already encoded it will not encode it again. You are correct that complications could arise if you use a difficult URL but you will have to manually make cases and exceptions for those specific URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I guess one way would be to read the HTTP-headers, especially the `Content-type` header, and evaluate whether it is an image or not.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378915/header-only-retrieval-in-php-via-curl) discuss how to check http headers using curl.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the MIME type.

```
echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
```

and use it against common image mime types viz. image/gif, image/png, etc.

Comment: it uses browsers type and it cant be changed.

Comment: I can create web.php shell and send it to the server with image/gif, image/png, etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. Include the HTTP header in the output by setting `CURLOPT_HEADER` via [curl_setopt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).
2. Parse the header, e.g using [http_parse_headers](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.http-parse-headers.php).
3. Check whether the content-type header field indicates an image type.

You might also want to set the request method to HEAD by setting `CURLOPT_NOBODY` if you are only interested in the content type.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $c = curl_init();

    curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'HEAD' );
    curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true );
    curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_URL, 'your.url' );

    curl_exec($c);

    $content_type = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
```

And check for allowed content-type.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [getimagesize](http://de.php.net/getimagesize)

```
<?php
    $i = getimagesize('http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/bd294ce7ff4c43b6aad4aa4169fb819b.jpg');
    print_r($i);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 220
    [1] => 250
    [2] => 2
    [3] => width="220" height="250"
    [bits] => 8
    [channels] => 3
    [mime] => image/jpeg
)
```

In case its not image you'll get `false`

```
$i = getimagesize('http://stackoverflow.com');
var_dump($i);
```

Output:

```
bool(false)
```