# PHP get remote file mime-type

Tags: php, mime-types

Hey what is the fastest way to check remote file mime-type... Im thinking about reading some from the first bytes, and maybe more... I spend some hours to think how to make the things right, but nothing on my mind... I must check IF the remote file is mp3, but it must be fastcheck...

Comment: Define "remote file"? How is it being accessed? HTTP? SMB? NFS? FTP? IMAP?

Comment: Maybe this could help you: [get_headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)

Comment: What If I only the know the extension of file instead of actual filename then header wont work in that case. Right? What would be solution then through HTTP?

Answer (score 16):

PHP curl_getinfo()

```
<?php
    # the request
    $ch = curl_init('http://www.google.com');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_exec($ch);

    # get the content type
    echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);

    # output
    // text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
?>
```

output

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 09 Apr 2010 20:35:12 GMT
Expires: Sun, 09 May 2010 20:35:12 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
Server: gws
Content-Length: 219
```

To actually confirm if the file contains actual MP3 data or any other media format, I use [getID3()](http://www.getid3.org/demo/).

Comment: Hmm interesting thing, I made file john.mp3 with content <?php blabla ?> and scripts says its a "audio/mpeg", can this be fixed?

Comment: Unfortunately php Mime-type is generated using just the file extension and not the actual file contents. You would have to make use of some third party app to actually verify that the file actually contains valid mp3 data.

Comment: If you don't want to load the entire file, just read the information about it, you can use these options instead: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);

Answer (score 6):

Make a HEAD request. See what Content-Type the server claims it is.

[This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378915/header-only-retrieval-in-php-via-curl) discusses accessing HTTP headers via PHP.

Answer (score 2):

When checking only the `Content-Type` of the remote server you're trusting it:

- The remote server could be malicious and serve a wrong Content-Type on purpose
- Content-Type is generated using the file extension, so a malicious user could store a wrong file type with an authorized extension to bypass your security

A safer approach is download the file in a temporary folder and then use [`mime_content_type`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) to check the MIME-type locally using `magic.mime`.

This technique only use the *magic number*, only reading the first bytes (header) of the file, that can be bypassed.

The most secure approach is to use a library that verify that the given file is valid for the required type it should be.