# Checking media type of audio and video from external links in php

Tags: php, mime-types

Does any one know how to check media types of audio and video from external urls.

```
function get_url_mime_type($url) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_exec($ch);
    return curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
}
```

Comment: you mean the media's MIME type ? or its codec ? what have you tried ?

Comment: yes media's MIME type

Comment: Hope the answer helps.

Answer (score -1):

To get file's MIME, use the following codes:

```
<?php
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME, "/usr/share/misc/magic"); // return mime type a.k.a. mimetype extension

/* get mime-type for a specific file */
$filename = "/usr/local/something.txt";
echo $finfo->file($filename);
?>
```

---

To get the extension of the file:

```
$tokens = explode('.', $filename);
$extension = $tokens[count($tokens)-1];
```

---

To get the MIME type of external file, either you can use cURL HEAD request to get the header  ( may not be accurate , as web server may not response with correct answer ), or use [getID3](http://www.getid3.org/demo/).

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656889/php-get-remote-file-mime-type) also asks the similar thing. Take a look of it.

Reference: [finfo_open()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php)

Comment: if i use curl_getinfo() some times for audio urls i got media type "text/html" that's the problem.

Comment: Do you use HEAD request as my referenced question ?

Comment: got it ! but you are not requesting a file. You are requesting a page. Your URL should look like http://www.example.com/example.mp3