# Secure remote image upload from URL

Tags: php, image, security

Im trying to upload an image to my server given a url pointing to an image.
I was wondering, which measures should i take into account to prevent remote file inclusion attacks, how can i make sure that the url a user provides really points to an image and not to a php file

Thanks

Comment: This probably won't fully answer your question, but have you looked at [Header only retrieval in PHP using CURL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1379319/3033053)

Comment: What if the image isn't actually a file but a php dinamically generated image?

Comment: The head request will also give you the content-type information without pulling down the entire file (*I think*).  I doubt that's enough as far as security from attacks, but that's why I posted as a comment and not an answer. :)