# loadHTML - Pull only headers to retrieve meta?

Tags: php

I am using a function with loadHTML($url) to retrieve meta tags from my other site.

It works but page load times increase by 4-5 seconds.

The target pages are bit heavy, Is it possible to load just the header of remote ?

or is there any alternative ?

Comment: try to look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378915/header-only-retrieval-in-php-via-curl

Comment: oops! sorry. yea misunderstood it. i dont think theres a way to do that

Answer (score 0):

I switched to get_meta_tags http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php.

It is 'bit' better now. I think the function still pull entire html but parse only till

I guess an api as suggested by "Paul Crovella" will resolve the issue completely.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can download only headers using [HEAD](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) HTTP method instead GET.
To make request i recommend use [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)

Comment: Oh, i mean another head.
Then @PaulCrovella, you can use Guzzle [streams](http://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/http-client/response.html#streaming-responses) for this case. Just abort when you find closing head tag.